# How should I connect a light fixture to this wire setup?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am installing a new wall sconce to replace the old one and am uncertain if the copper wires sticking out are indeed the ground wires. I am wondering why they are set up this way instead of the usual single bare copper wire. Also, I am uncertain about the red wire and why it is there. The new fixture only has black, white and ground. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Ground wire can only be bare or if covered must be green(maybe with yellow line).  The red might be a switched hot or a 5 to 10% chance of being extra.  You did take a picture of how the old light was connected?  Right?

Comment: Did you take a picture of how the previous fixture was wired?

Comment: @Ecnerwal i usually do! But forgot this time to do it :(

Comment: In the future when removing a fixture, don't take apart the wire nuts to remove the fixture pigtail wires. Just cut em and cap em.  Then you'll know exactly where the wires go, since they're still on there!  The person who grabs the fixture out of your trash will hate you, so leave them a few inches.

Answer (score 3):

**Normally** (but you really should have taken a before picture to refer to):

The bare wires are grounds, and they are all twisted together because all grounds must be connected and you have more than one cable in this box. They should have a wire nut or crimp securely joining them and they should be connected to a grounding screw on the metal box. Some go to other fixtures/devices.

The white wires are neutrals. White wires are not ALWAYS neutrals, but here, they appear to be. Some go to other fixtures/devices.

The black wires are un-switched hots (live). Some go to other fixtures/devices. You won't use them here. Leave them as they are.

The red wire is typically the switched hot coming back from the switch (which gets un-switched hot from the black wire in that cable, and neutral from the white wire in that cable, even if it does not use neutral, because a replacement might, and NEC 2011 and later require neutral at switch boxes.)

So ground to ground (and add a wirenut,) white to white and black (fixture) to red (junction box.)

99.9% likely that's correct in this case. Can't be 100% without actually checking, since people sometimes do odd things.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the grounds need to be connected to the steel box.  One of the holes in the box is smaller than the others, and it is pre-threaded #10-32. Any #10-32 machine screw can go in there; they even make green ones specifically for this job.

Go to a high-class local family-owned hardware store (you know, the kind of place you think is overpriced)... they sell those screws for a dime in singles, and also will sell you 1 foot of wire at sane cost.  Get 1' of bare #12 ground and have them cut it into two 6" lengths.  #12 is the universal donor, it'll work in all your normal receptacle and lighting circuits.

Once the box is grounded, the fixture should pick up ground via the mounting screws, but feel free to add any ground wire to the bundle.

4 white wires implies 4 black wires, which I assume are all connected together under the wire nut there.  Those are almost certainly "always-hot".  Most people want their light to respond to command of a light switch, so that'd be the wrong hot to use. Leave that alone.

The solitary red wire cannot possibly have any purpose except to be the "switched-hot" for the light.

The 4 white wires bundled can only be the neutral.